# jQuery equivalent for createElement?

Tags: jquery, dom

```
function ytplayer_render_playlist(){
    for(var i=0;i<ytplayer_playlist.length;i++){
      var img = document.createElement("img");
      img.src="http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + ytplayer_playlist[i] + "/default.jpg";
      var a=document.createElement("a");
      a.href="#ytplayer";
      a.onclick=(function(j){
           return function(){
                ytplayer_playitem=j;
                ytplayer_playlazy(1000);
               };
        })(i);
      a.appendChild(img);
     document.getElementById("ytplayer_div2").appendChild(a);
    }
}
```

I can convert simple jquery codes but this one is too complicated for me.

Comment: Why do you need to convert it?

Comment: I just want to enhance and practice jquery..

Answer (score 4):

You can create elements with the same dollar sign syntax:

```
var img = $('<img />', {
    src: "http://img.youtube.com/vi/" + ytplayer_playlist[i] + "/default.jpg"
});
```

Although I'm not too sure why you'd need to do this. The code works as-is and seems to be from a plugin, which you'll have to re-translate every time it's updated.

Comment: I have tried that code but I think it has lacking. it won't work . maybe append() I'm not sure..

Comment: @MarkBean: I won't translate the whole thing for you. Do as much as you can and then a little more.

Comment: If you tried just copy and paste, looks like there's a syntax error in the code there. there's a comma after `jpg",` that shouldn't be there.

Comment: @FelipeTadeo: The comma won't throw a syntax error, but thanks for catching that. Not too sure how it got there.